# l'Hopital's rule in context with CDF and its density

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Consider, that the following $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{G(x)}{x} $ exists with $G(x) =-ln(1-F(x))$.

F is an arbitrary CDF with its density f.
I want to proof:

$$m(s)= s\int_0^{\infty} e^{st} (1-F(x))dx +1 = \infty \Leftrightarrow \lim_{x\to \infty} G'(x)=0 $$

From  $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{G(x)}{x} $ I can conlude using l'Hopital's rule  $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{G(x)}{x}= \lim_{x\to \infty} G'(x)$

How can I go on from that?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}G'(x)=0$ always regardless of any conditions. By the way: what $+1$ for? What is $s$?

Comment: $s>0$. Actually you conisder the moment generating function $m(s)= E(e^{sX}) $

Comment: This form can be written in the form with +1.

Comment: So $m(s)$ is the moment generating function of which variable?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I am just trying to understand your question. Moment generating functions are defined as expected values. If the $m(s)$ you defined above a genuine mgf? If so, the mgf of which variable?

Comment: It is an mgf of an random variable which can be positive and 0.

Comment: Sorry for bothering: I can't help :-/

Comment: No problem.  Thank you for trying :)